# Can't get the TinyMCE to work in django admin

Tags: django, django-tinymce

I follow the instruction in [here](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) to install the TinyMCE into the django Admin backend.

But it is not working. When checking the console log, I saw this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js Failed to load
```

DO I need to manually adding the js file? The instruction in the github does not mention this.

**UPDATE**

Indeed to make it work, will have to move the tiny_mce to your static folder.
Here is my solution for anyone who also have similar problem.

```
settins.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
#this is for localhost development, if you are in production enviroment, you will need to remove the STATICFILES_DIRS and define your STATIC_ROOT
 TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
 'plugins' : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,pagebreak",
'theme': "advanced",

'theme_advanced_buttons1' : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,fontselect,fontsizeselect,fullscreen,code,|,preview,image,media",
'theme_advanced_buttons2' : "table,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,forecolor,backcolor, emotions,|,pagebreak,paste",
'theme_advanced_buttons3 ': "",
'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : "top",
'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' : "left",
'width': '700',
'height': '400'
}


admin.py
class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
                js = ('/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',)
```

Comment: check the permission of your static folder

Comment: And copy the tiny_mce folder in media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons for this issue.

1.) You have the required files but on a different location than specified in your script tag. Change the url in your script tag to the valid location and it will work

2.) You do not have the required files. Download the source files and place them in the specified location and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Django TinyMCE has the media url as default value, as you can see in the docs:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL (default: settings.MEDIA_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT (default: settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce')
```

If you prefer to use the static files in the static folder, you have to set these values to the correct path. I'd sugest:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = settings.STATIC_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce'
```

Now you have to ensure you're using the "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder" in your STATICFILES_FINDERS settings, in order to not have to copy the files in development environment, and to be collected with collectstatic.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:-

1. First uninstalling tinymce

   pip uninstall django-tinymce4
2. and Then re-installing tinymce

It worked for me